# import single Vuetify component in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify in nuxt.js.
How to use this only in dashboard layout?
in nuxt.config.js

```
 modules: [
        //['nuxt-leaflet', { /* module options */}],
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        '@nuxtjs/auth',
        '@nuxtjs/toast',
        ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {rtl: true}],
        // 'nuxt-i18n',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) with [tree-shaking](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#treeshake)? If so, you can just import specific vuetify component into specific `.vue` component:

```
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib';
```

and add:

```
components: { VTextField }
```

According to the [@nuxtjs/vuetify](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) module documentation, if you using the `treeShake` [option](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#treeshake), by default your Nuxt.js app will use only the needed vuetify component, and the bundle size didn't increase.

> Uses [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) to enable automatic [tree-shaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/). Enabled only for production by default.

**Another thing**, If you are using `Nuxt >= 2.9.0`, use buildModules section instead:

```
{
  buildModules: [
    // Simple usage
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',

    // With options
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { /* module options */ }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: ok. but styles change. vuetify/style/src/_reset.scss . and conflict by bootstrap

Comment: Please try import {VTextField} from 'vuetify/lib' and add components: { VTextField }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [NuxtJS Vuetify Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) (It seems that you are), I assume that your `package.json` does not have `vuetify` listed there, because it is the `@nuxtjs/vuetify` that imports it. Thus, you can't import it using only the module name. I suggest you to import it with it's complete path like the following:

```
import { VCard } from '~/node_modules/vuetify/lib';
```

Then register the component, of course.